# Percentage Calculation - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, percentage

Background: An **Alliance** has a lot of **Players**, which have a lot of **Towns**. Every Town  belongs to an **Ocean**.

*My Problem:*

I'm trying to calculate **the percentage of Towns in a certain Ocean**. E.g.:

```
<% @alliance.players.each do |p| %>
  <% p.towns.each do |t| %>
    <%= t.ocean %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This gives me all the `Town's Ocean's` of a given alliance. The output will look like this:

```
54 54 54 54 54 35 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 45 45 45 45 45 45 54 54 54 44 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 44 54 44 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54
```

So we have the **Majority: 54** and **Few: 44**.

How can i calculate the results so i get the Percentage of Towns in a specific Ocean so i get an output of e.g.: `Ocean 54: 83%`, `Ocean 44: 17%`.

Comment: You shouldn't do this calculation in View.. do it inside the controller and then use the variable inside the view. I don't have the data, so I can't try, but you could do the whole stuff in DB level using ActiveRecord methods..

Comment: Or write a helper. Or even better, move this logic to model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
percentages = p.towns.group_by(&:ocean).map {|ocean, towns| [ocean, (towns.count/p.towns.count.to_f * 100).round(0)]}.to_h
perentages.each {|ocean, percentage| puts "Ocean #{ocean}: #{percentage}%"}
```

Comment: Could you join me in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64334/percentage-calculation